# ContainerView on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, fragmentpageradapter, container-view

I created a Container View in my iOS App Storyboard. I want to page horizontally in one of the cells in the UICollectionView (like a FragmentPager of Android). However, an error occurs if you put in the Container View in a UICollectionViewCell:

> Storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime

Comment: Why don't you use UIScrollView inside the cell? The collectionView can scroll vertically, while the UIScrollView's inside the cell can scroll horizontally

Comment: UICollectionView can horizontal scroll.
But I want to use uitableview or uicollectionview...
is this bad idea...?